# Where to download Dynamic CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I want to download Microsoft Dynamic CRM 2011 for trial version.

Can anyone share virtual machine for this ?

I want to create one application in .NET which can do some API call to create lead/account into CRM.
For time being, I need to have trial version of Dynamic CRM 2011 inhous setup with VM.

Please share if any one know

Thank You

Dhaval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=27822).

You can download CRM 2011 VM from PartnerSource if you are Microsoft Partner. This is the [Link](https://mbs.microsoft.com/partnersource/deployment/methodology/vpc/MSD_CRM2011VirtualMachine.htm) to download.

But if you are not microsoft partner you can build your own VM and install CRM 2011 on it. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/girishr/archive/2011/01/26/building-a-crm-2011-virtual-machine-video-walkthrough.aspx) is very useful article for Building a CRM 2011 Virtual Machine.

Vanilla Windows Server Virtual Machine (180 days trial) can be downloaded [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=16572). It is ready to use VM and you can install whatever you need on it.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I don't have partner account. Is there any alternative other then creating vm manually ? In Vanilla windows server VM , require to install Dynamic CRM 2011 or it is already there ?

Comment: can you please also provide related link OF SDK and how to connect virtual machine - CRM from .NET ?

Comment: sorry to bother you much, Can I use Vannila windows server 2008 VM on windows 7 machine ? To setup CRM 2011, do I have to install CRM 2011 separately on this VM ? please guide. thanks.

Comment: I think you will find that VM needs hyper-V, but you may be able to convert and run on something like VirtualBox on Windows 7 instead. Yes, you will need to install SQL Server and CRM 2011 separately, they won't be rolled into that VM already. Oh, and buy more RAM!

Comment: As Adam said, you can convert it to use with virtual box. Windows 7 does support virtual box and hyper v. Once you have installed SQL and CRM on it, it will be ready to use.

Comment: Just google "dynamics CRM 2011 developer toolkit". Download it and you will get very good examples in samplecode folder.